# Stack Overflow Exception C#

Tags: c#, recursion, math, stack-overflow, getter

I have encountered this error

> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

The source of error come from this code

```
 internal class Record
{
    [Name("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Name("Principal")]
    public int Principal { get { return Math.Abs(Principal); } set {; } }

}
```

I searched the error and it state the error occur because of `recursive`. I think my `Principal` method is not recursive method.

Comment: It is recursive. When you try to read the Principal property you call the get accessor and the get accessor reads the Principal property starting the infinite loop

Comment: Your principal method isn't a method either, by the way; these things (with get/set) are called "properties". It's always helpful to use the exact terminology when talking with another dev because you may one day have a class with a property and a method, and if you say "the method is crashing" when you meant the property, you'll cause a lot of confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want to consider one of these:

```
internal class Record
{
    [Name("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Name("Principal")]
    public int Principal { get; set; }

    [Name("AbsPrincipal")]
    public int AbsPrincipal { get { return Math.Abs(Principal); } set; }

}
```

```
internal class Record
{
    [Name("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Name("Principal")]
    private int _principal = 0;
    public int Principal { 
      get => _principal; 
      set => _principal = Math.Abs(value); 
    }

}
```

Any property or method that returns the result of getting its own value with nothing to stop it will overflow the stack. Recursive things that at work correctly usually have something with a condition that eventually changes state and stops the recursion (doesn't return the result of getting its own value)

Take a look at the first one: we don't make the property math.abs itself, we make it abs something else - this cannot recurse unless the something else were to return the first thing (then the recursion would flip flop between them)

The second one is probably more like what you want to do- again we abs something else (a backing variable) rather than the property itself preventing recursive overflow. In this one I abs on the set because it seems you never wanted to retrieve the non Abs value for principal so we might as well abs it when we store it then we can just retrieve it a million times without abs each time.. of course if you ever need private access to the non Abs'd variable you should do the abs on the get.. or if you know your use case will be that to store it a million times and only get it once, again do the abs on the get rather than the set. The typical program behavior I would expect in most cases is to set fewer times than get so we can avoid unnecessary work by choosing carefully when to do the abs

Comment: I have tried your code. But an error popup. It says ` Exception thrown: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException' in CsvHelper.dll `. How should I approach this issue

Comment: Probably that the "Principal" column in your csv contains values that cannot be converted to int; the problem isn't "my code" per se - all my code did was replicate "your code" - your code would also experience such an error. You might have to do something like `[Name("Principal")]
    private int _principal = 0;
    public string Principal { 
      get => _principal.ToString(); 
      set => _principal = Math.Abs(int.TryParse(value, out var i) ? i : 0); 
    }`

Answer (score -1):

As Steve suggested, you can calling Principal property in get of Principal. Hence recursive.

Did you mean to return Math.Abs(typeof(Principal));

Comment: Typeof returns a Type, which you can't use Abs on

Comment: Ah good point. Thanks