# Why does this code throw StackOverFlow Exception?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow, getter-setter

I was learning about getters and setters in C# and came across this code. I understand what's wrong here with the c# context. It has no compile-time errors but throws runtime exception. Can anybody explain what causes the call stack overflow?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        Console.WriteLine(test.Company);
    }
}

class Test
{
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return Company;
        }
        set
        {
            Company = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the getter for `Company` returns `Company` which returns `Company` which returns `Company` which returns `Company`...until the stack overflows.

Comment: You should have looked in your Stack Trace and you would have immediately found out that you are missing a backing field and you are assigning a value to the Company property which assigns the value to itself which assigns the value to itself which assigns the value to itself... Endlessly

Comment: StackOverflow is full of stack overflows today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084798/stack-overflow-exception-c-sharp/63084864?noredirect=1#comment111558934_63084864 - I wonder if these gets closed as duplicates of each other would it cause a StackOverflowoverflow.. :)

Comment: @legacycode I think it's the getter rather than the setter but I getter what you mean. Good point about the stack trace, you should write it up into an answer - it would be a good education point

Comment: It’s actually both that will cause a Stackoverflow. 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StackOverflow Exception from get and set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977482/stackoverflow-exception-from-get-and-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you call your property in your getter.
You can do two things: add a field/member to  you class:

```
class Test
{
    private string company;   
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return company;
        }
        set
        {
            company = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or change it to

```
public string Company{get; set;}
```