# StackOverFlow Exception while creating objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to display the details of the movie but I am getting StackOverFlow exception in cast class where I am returning actorNames array.

I am trying to make the movie object. In movie object, I am creating objects for Cast and Genre class and passing them in movie class constructor with the data.

Kindly let me know how I can correct this issue. This issue might exist for Genre class as well. Please let me know if there is any case like that as well.

```
// Genre Class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_4
{
    class Genre
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> genre = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public string[] genreName { get { return genreName; } set { } }
        public string[] genreDescription { get { return genreDescription; } }

        public Genre() {
            setGlobalGenreDictionary();
        }

        public Genre(string[] nameOfGenre) {
            this.genreName = nameOfGenre;
            setGenreDecsription(nameOfGenre);
        }

        public void setGenreDecsription(string[] genreName) {
            int i = 0;
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> gen in genre) {
                if (gen.Key == genreName[i]) {
                    genreDescription[i] = gen.Value;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        public void setGlobalGenreDictionary() {
            genre.Add("Action", "Associated with particular types of spectacle (e.g., explosions, chases, combat)");
            genre.Add("Adventure", "Implies a narrative that is defined by a journey (often including some form of pursuit) and is usually located within a fantasy or exoticized setting. Typically, though not always, such stories include the quest narrative. The predominant emphasis on violence and fighting in action films is the typical difference between the two genres.");
            genre.Add("Animation", "A film medium in which the film's images are primarily created by computer or hand and the characters are voiced by actors. Animation can otherwise incorporate any genre and subgenre and is often confused as a genre itself");
            genre.Add("Comedy", "Defined by events that are primarily intended to make the audience laugh");
            genre.Add("Drama", "Focused on emotions and defined by conflict, often looking to reality rather than sensationalism.");
            genre.Add("Fantasy", "Films defined by situations that transcend natural laws and/or by settings inside a fictional universe, with narratives that are often inspired by or involve human myths. The genre typically incorporates non-scientific concepts such as magic, mythical creatures, and supernatural elements.");
            genre.Add("History", "Films that either provide more-or-less accurate representations of historical accounts or depict fictional narratives placed inside an accurate depiction of a historical setting.");
            genre.Add("Horror", "Films that seek to elicit fear or disgust in the audience for entertainment purposes.");
            genre.Add("Noir", "A genre of stylish crime dramas particularly popular during the 1940s and '50s. They were often reflective of the American society and culture at the time.");
            genre.Add("Science Fiction", "Films are defined by a combination of imaginative speculation and a scientific or technological premise, making use of the changes and trajectory of technology and science. This genre often incorporates space, biology, energy, time, and any other observable science.");
            genre.Add("Thriller", "Films that evoke excitement and suspense in the audience. The suspense element found in most films' plots is particularly exploited by the filmmaker in this genre. Tension is created by delaying what the audience sees as inevitable, and is built through situations that are menacing or where escape seems impossible.");
            genre.Add("Western", "A genre in which films are set in the American West during the 19th century and embodies the \"spirit, the struggle and the demise of the new frontier.\" These films will often feature horse riding, violent and non-violent interaction with Native-American tribes, gunfights, and technology created during the industrial revolution.");

        }
    }
}

//Movie Class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_4
{
    class Movie
    {
        int movieId;
        string movieTitle;
        string storyline;
        double rating;
        int year;
        Cast cast;
        Genre genre;

        public Movie(int id, string title, string story, double rating, int yr, Cast castObj, Genre genObj) {
            movieId = id;
            movieTitle = title;
            storyline = story;
            this.rating = rating;
            year = yr;
            this.cast = castObj;
            this.genre = genObj;
        }

        public void getMovie() {
            Console.WriteLine("Movie:" + this.movieTitle + "\n"
                + "Year:" + this.year + "\n"
                + "IMDB Rating:" + this.rating + "/10\n "
                + "Storyline:" + this.storyline );

            Console.WriteLine("Cast:");

            try
            {
                int noOfMembers = this.cast.actorNames.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < noOfMembers; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(cast.roles + ":" + cast.actorNames);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
            }

            int noOfGenres = this.genre.genreName.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfGenres; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.genre.genreName + ":" + this.genre.genreDescription);
            }

        }

    }

}

//Cast Class:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_4
{
    
    class Cast
    {
                
        public string[] actorNames {
            get
            {
                    return actorNames;
            } 
            set { } }
    
    
        public string[] roles { get { return roles; } set { } }

        int referenceToMovie;

        public Cast(string[] actorNames, string[] roles, int reference) {
            this.actorNames = actorNames;
            this.roles = roles;
            this.referenceToMovie = reference;
        }
    }

    
}

//Main Class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string castNames = "Kenneth Branagh,Patrick Doyle,Chris Hemsworth,Natalie Portman";
            string castRoles = "Director,Music,Actor,Actor";
            string genresOfTheMovie = "Action,Adventure,Fantasy";

            Movie thor = new Movie(0800369, "Thor", "The powerful but arrogant god Thor is cast out of Asgard to live amongst humans in Midgard (Earth), " +
                "where he soon becomes one of their finest defenders.", 7.0, 2011, new Cast(castNames.Split(','), castRoles.Split(','), 0800369), new Genre(genresOfTheMovie.Split(',')));
            thor.getMovie();

            //Movie ironman = new Movie();
            //Movie hulk = new Movie();
            //Movie avengers = new Movie();
            //Movie blackPanther = new Movie();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `genreName` and `genreDescription` property getters return themselves; that's an excellent way to recurse forever.  You have a debugger.  Try stepping through your code and see what happens.  A stack overflow is generally the result of unexpected (/undesigned) recursion.

Comment: In the Movie class you have 2 `for` loops in which you never use the `i` iterator, is that intentional? Because you're just writing the same thing to the console on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please find some tutorial on how properties work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this code throw StackOverFlow Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63094187/why-does-this-code-throw-stackoverflow-exception)

Comment: You're just writing **every** genreName and **every** genreDescription on **each** iteration of the loop. Did you mean to do `this.genre.genreName[i]` and `this.genre.genreDescription[i]` instead? Same with the noOfMembers loop

Comment: `public string[] actorNames { get { return actorNames;}` should have a backing field or an auto property. Likewise `public string[] roles { get { return roles; } set { } }`. Long and short of it: you need to do some [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code:
Genre:
you set a global genre Dictionary on every initialization of Genre.  This means you'll be adding all of the items every time Genre you try to create a Genre.

```
        private static Dictionary<string, string> genre = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//make this static
public static void SetGlobalGenreDictionary()
```

and then call it

```
Genre.SetGlobalGenreDictionary();
```

in your program

For your properties, they are what is causing your StackOverflow issue.
There are a couple of ways to write these, but your version will keep calling itself causing the stack overflow.

```
//Option 1: 
        public string[] GenreName1 { get; set; }

        //Option 2: 
        private string[] genreName2;
        public string[] GenreName2 { 
            get
            {
                return genreName2;
            }
            set
            {
                //you have to write a Set method body if you write a get method.  Otherwise nothing will happen.  If you don't want to set it, don't write a set method at all.  
                genreName2 = value;
            }
        }
```

There are other issues, but this should get you started on your homework problem.